# Setting focus to an anchor using jquery does not scroll it into view in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small panel with a fixed height that contains a list of anchors for search results. I'd like to overtake the tab key so it will only go to anchors on the page that are part of these results.

When the tab key is hit, I set the focus to the next eligible anchor. In Safari, FF, Chrome, this also causes the newly focused item to be scrolled into view (just like a natural tab event would do), but not IE.

The relevant code follows.

CSS

```
#search-results {  height: 200px; overflow: auto; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="search-results-panel">
    <h2 id="StrSearchResults">Search Results:</h2>
    <ul id="search-results">
        <li><a class="item">Item One</a></li>
        <li><a class="item">Item Two</a></li>
        <li class="focus"><a class="item">Item Three</a></li>
        <li><a class="item">Item Four</a></li>
        <li><a class="item">Item Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, a', function(e) {
    var focusable, next, prev;

    if ( e.keyCode === 9 ) {                // tab
        var selected = $('li.focus a.item')[0];

        e.preventDefault();

        focusable =   $(document).find('li a.item').filter(':visible');

        if ( e.shiftKey ) {
            prev = focusable.eq(focusable.index(selected)-1); 

            if (prev.length) {
                prev.focus();
            }
        }
        else {
            next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(selected)+1);

            if (next.length) {
                next.focus();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

fwiw, this is part of an app, so normal browser behavior doesn't apply here.

Thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: Can u post a (non)working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to as the tab key is handled at the jsfiddle level and I don't get any keydown events for it. I'm not a jsfiddle expert though, so maybe there's a way?  Plus, keep in mind that it is just IE where it isn't working.

Comment: There is one thing to mention that in the html the <a> references are missing their href. In my real code, they are there.